# Trouble Getting Jquery to Work Monaca Online IDE

Tags: jquery, monaca

Hi trying to get jQuery to work on Monaca UI online IDE. I checked on the config tab (shows jQuery Monaca Version 2.0.3) installed by default.

However the simple script below fails to run in the app window or debugger but works fine in a browser window in a local environment.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#showHide1").hide();
$("#contact1").click(function() {
$("#showHide1").toggle();
});



$("#showHide2").hide();
$("#contact2").click(function() {
$("#showHide2").toggle();
});

});



        <div style="text-align: center">
        <h4 id="contact1">A Name</h4>
        <p id="showHide1">
        Some content
        <br />
        </p>
        <br />
        <a class="button setButWidth" href="mailto:----------@----------------.com">Email</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="button setButWidth" href="tel:012345678">Call</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h4 id="contact2">A Name</h4>
        <p id="showHide2">
        <br />
        <br />
        Some content
        <br />
        </p>
        <br />
        <a class="button setButWidth" href="mailto:--------@--------.com">Email</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="button setButWidth" href="tel:012345678">Call</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
```

I have tried adding my script in the head of the index.html file as an include and in a script tag also in the page body in question itself in a script tag but no dice.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/JimmyG/pen/vLNMGp) here

What am I missing here?

J